# A better way to create a base class method that depends on a lot of type parameters values from subclasses

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop

I have an abstract base class HandlerProvider with (a lot of) generic type parameters. The parameters are used to determine (using reflection) what classes inherit from a specified interface, and have a custom attribute of a specified type, that contains an enum value of yet another type. (All the types are specified in type parameters.)

Next, I have two sub classes TriggerHandlerProvider and ActionHandlerProvider that implement the abstract class, and use the ClassTypes dictionary that is initialized in the abstract class.

My question is: Is there a better (more elegant) OOP way to determine the ClassTypes dictionary (getting rid of at least some type parameters) without having to duplicate the code from DetermineTypesToHandle in each sub class?

Code follows below.

```
public interface IAttribute<out TEnum>
{
    TEnum GetValue();
}

public abstract class HandlerProvider<THandlerInterface, TInterface, TAttribute, TTypeEnum> : IHandlerProvider
    where TAttribute : Attribute, IAttribute<TTypeEnum>
{
    // Maps enum values to System.Type instances.
    protected readonly Dictionary<TTypeEnum, Type> ClassTypes;

    protected HandlerProvider(List<TTypeEnum> typeIds)
    {
        ClassTypes = new Dictionary<TTypeEnum, Type>();
        DetermineTypesToHandle(typeIds);
    }

    private void DetermineTypesToHandle(List<TTypeEnum> typeIds)
    {
        if (typeIds == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        IEnumerable<Type> classes = GetTypesWithAttribute(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        if (classes == null) return;
        foreach (Type classType in classes)
        {
            if (typeof(TInterface).IsAssignableFrom(classType))
            {
                TAttribute attribute = GetTypeAttribute(classType);
                TTypeEnum attributeValue = attribute != null ? attribute.GetValue() : default(TTypeEnum);
                if (!Equals(attributeValue, default(TTypeEnum)) && typeIds.Exists(tt => Equals(tt, attributeValue)))
                {
                    ClassTypes.Add(attributeValue, classType);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private TAttribute GetTypeAttribute(Type classType)
    {
        return Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(classType, typeof(TAttribute)) as TAttribute;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithAttribute(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return from t in assembly.GetTypes()
               where t.IsDefined(typeof(TAttribute), false)
               select t;
    }
}

public class TriggerHandlerProvider : HandlerProvider<ITriggerHandler, ITrigger, TriggerTypeAttribute, ETriggerType>
{
    public TriggerHandlerProvider(List<ETriggerType> typeIds)
        : base(typeIds)
    {
        // Use the ClassTypes property from the base class to create a new TriggerHandler.
    }
}

public class ActionHandlerProvider : HandlerProvider<IActionHandler, IAction, ActionTypeAttribute, EActionType>
{
    public ActionHandlerProvider(List<EActionType> typeIds)
        : base(typeIds)
    {
        // Use the ClassTypes property from the base class to create a new ActionHandler.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "normal" flow you expect to happens? On other words, what you would like to do (without thinking of the specificities of your code). So, please, show us what your code should do. This will make easier to help :) (for me, at least)

Comment: More... What is "EActionType"? What is ETriggerType and how is it possible to cast them to TTypeEnum? This should give you an error right away (I make a test and my VS do not let this even compile saying that it can't cast List<EActionType> to List<TTypeEnum> (I'm considering them classes and EActionType is derived from TTypeEnum)

Comment: ETriggerType and EActionType are enums, not classes: public enum ETriggerType and public enum EActionType. Those enums are passed in the TTypeEnum generic type parameter.

Comment: Oh! I see, TType is a generic parameter. Sorry, I let this pass. :)

Comment: Ok.. Let me see if I understood. You have classes that implement some interfaces (that define the kind of Handler Provider they are), and an attribute that define an enum value that create some "specificity" and will be used by the derived handler classes to execute code from that class, depending on user/code path. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Jauch, thanks for your replies. All the generic type parameter values, including the one for the enum, are specific for the sub classes. They are used by the common base class method DetermineTypesToHandle. I am just doubting whether I should get rid of the type params (or some of them) and implement some specifics of  the common method in the sub handler classes (since those sub classes already ARE specific ;-)

Comment: lol

I don't think it is necessary. But if the purpose of the "abstract base class" is just to populate the library, you co in fact do the things a little different. I'll make a couple of suggestions as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeroen, I suggest you to simplify.

With the following schema, you need only one attribute (woth the enumeration value) on the classes that will hold the code for the specific handlers.

Each specific handler must implement an interface, that is its connection with the "higher level" handler provider (for example, your ActionHandlerProvider).

I put the code to fill the handlers collection in an static class, as it seems more natural to me, but it's easy to make it again a "base class". In any case you need only two parameters, one template, and one interface to it work.

The interface can hold common methods and data that can be passed to the specific handler in a standard way, so the Handler provider do not have to worry about the specificities of each handler (on modt of cases anyway)

Bellow is the code with an example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class HandlerAttribute : Attribute
    {
        protected string fType;

        public HandlerAttribute(string type)
        {
            fType = type;
        }

        public string HandlerType
        {
            get { return fType; }
            set { fType = value; }
        }
    }

    public interface IHandlerA
    {
        //commom interface for handlers of type HandlerA
        string Name { get; }
    }

    public enum EHandlerATypes
    {
        A,
        B
    }

    [HandlerAttribute("A")]
    public class SpecificHandlerATypeA : IHandlerA
    {

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "HandlerA type A"; }
        }
    }

    [HandlerAttribute("B")]
    public class SpecificHandlerATypeB : IHandlerA
    {

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "HandlerA type B"; }
        }
    }

    public class HandlerA
    {
        public Dictionary<EHandlerATypes, Type> fHandlerACollection;

        public HandlerA()
        {
            fHandlerACollection = HandlerSearchEngine.GetHandlersList<EHandlerATypes, IHandlerA>(new Assembly[] { this.GetType().Assembly });
        }
    }

    public static class HandlerSearchEngine
    {
        public static Dictionary<TEnum, Type> GetHandlersList<TEnum, THandler>(Assembly[] assemblyList)
        {
            if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
                throw new Exception("Invalid parameter TEnum");

            Dictionary<TEnum, Type> dic = new Dictionary<TEnum, Type>();

            foreach(Assembly assembly in assemblyList)
            {
                var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(THandler).IsAssignableFrom(t));
                foreach(Type type in types)
                {
                    HandlerAttribute ha = type.GetCustomAttribute<HandlerAttribute>();
                    TEnum handlerType = (TEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), ha.HandlerType, true);

                    if (dic.ContainsKey(handlerType))
                        throw new Exception("One handler with the same handler type already exists in the collection");

                    dic[handlerType] = type;
                }
            }

            return dic;
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HandlerA a = new HandlerA();
            foreach(KeyValuePair<EHandlerATypes, Type> pair in a.fHandlerACollection)
            {
                IHandlerA ha = (IHandlerA)Activator.CreateInstance(pair.Value);
                Console.WriteLine(ha.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this example will be:

```
HandlerA type A 
HandlerA type B
```

Hope this can help simplify things for you.